# Modify S3 bucket response?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to serve an HTML page from an S3 bucket, which I'm able to do w/o issue. I'd like to then have the S3 bucket response (the static webpage) include the request headers - can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Lambda@Edge with a cloudfront instance in front of your S3 bucket? https://medium.com/@tom.cook/edge-lambda-cloudfront-custom-headers-3d134a2c18a2 You can specify which headers to set within the lambda code as it intercepts the request and adds additional HTTP headers to requests before they’re returned to clients.

Comment: Thank you Woodrow - good suggestion. I was hoping to keep this project I'm doing really simplistic so adding a Lambda function in front of an S3 bucket request is something I'd like to shy away from if possible. I just need an S3 bucket to return the IP address of the connection via curl or wget. But b/c S3 only serves static content, I was hoping that by including the headers I could get the info. I need.